# Grouping by anonymous v.s. grouping by non-anonymous

Tags: linq, group-by

I need to group some data after it has arrived from server.

```
var result = context.GetData();

Assert.Equal(54, result.Count); // OK

var transactions = result.GroupBy(t => new //BeneficiaryGroup
                        {
                            BankAcronym = t.BankAcronym.Substring(4, 4),
                            DebitDate = t.DebitDate,
                            Key = t.Key
                        })
                    .OrderBy(g => g.Key.BankAcronym)
                    .ThenBy(g => g.Key.DebitDate)
                    .ThenBy(g => g.Key.Key)
                    .ToList();

Assert.Equal( 14, transactions.Count ); // OK
```

When I'm grouping by an anonymous object, the grouping is correctly done.

When I'm grouping by a **BeneficiaryGroup** object, with the exact same properties

```
public class BeneficiaryGroup 
{ 
    BankAcronym,
    DebitDate,
    Key
}
```

the grouping is not correctly done - the group has 54 records, as before grouping.

And I want to group the data by a class so I can return to the API consumer a collection already grouped.

Any ideas why this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous types get 'sensible' equality behaviour 'for free', which is why the grouping works as you expect in that case. When you switch to using a named class, it then becomes your responsibility as the class definer to provide equality behaviour, to allow a `BeneficiaryGroup` to be used as a grouping key in the manner you expect.

---

As it says in [the docs for `GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534501.aspx),

> The default equality comparer `Default` is used to compare keys.

where `Default` is [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms224763.aspx), which explains:

> The Default property checks whether type `T` implements the
>   `System.IEquatable<T>` interface and, if so, returns an
>   `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it
>   returns an `EqualityComparer<T>` that uses the overrides of
>   `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` provided by `T`.

And [for an anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx),

> Because the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods on anonymous types are
>   defined in terms of the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of the
>   properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if
>   all their properties are equal.

whereas for a named type that *doesn't* override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, you will get the `Object` implementations, which generally aren't useful.

Comment: Indeed, I should've thought about this.